# Create folder with Skydrive API

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive

In a Windows Phone 7(.5) application I am using Skydrive and want to create a folder.

How do I (or where can I find the API to) create a folder? So far I only found examples to scan and download files.

I'm using the LiveConnectClient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct link to creating folders (example is provided in several languages look for [C# for Windows Phone apps]:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531#creating_folders

SkyDrive API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521